# How to a get a continuous response from a REST server return in python flask with a single get request

Tags: python, rest, ssl, flask, https

Can we get a continuous data from REST server using python for a single GET request. I am using flask for the moment.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def hello_world():
   while True:
     return 'Hello World!'
```

This would return "Hello World!" once but I would want String to be sent continuous to the client till a server program is stopped or hardware stop(CTRL+C) is pressed. or even I would be happy to have the String or XML sent continuously for a given time.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? Can you give more details? This seems like an [XY](http://xyproblem.info/) problem.

Comment: I have a server running in VM. so using s_client (openssl), I get some data from the server. right now for a every request, we get the response from the server but only once, I want the data to be continuously received to the client for a single GET request till I stop the stream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, but it is not as simple as GET. You have to build the backend python to work asynchronously and send updates without a request. The best way that I have seen is using socket.io:

[socket.io](http://www.shanelynn.ie/asynchronous-updates-to-a-webpage-with-flask-and-socket-io/)

And here is a tutorial that shows a way of promoting the character string data you are asking about:

[Easy Web Sockets](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent)

It is kind of hard to give you a code snippet without more, as the phrase "Hello World" is static and you would not see changes, so it is not useful. But the second link shows you how to set it up to detect changes, confirm connections/disconnections and promote data from the server to the client.

If you get stuck again, edit the post with real code and real data.